# Why Need FaultContract, when we can just use FaultException?

Tags: c#, wcf

I was just checking the WCF `FaultContract`. As per it's definition it's used to send exception details to client. But we can just use `FaultException` to do that. SO why we need FaultContract. Below is my code

**ServiceData Class**

```
[DataContract]
public class ServiceData
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool Result { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorDetails { get; set; }
}
```

**IService1.cs**

```
[OperationContract]
ServiceData TestMethod();
```

**Service1.svc.cs**

```
 public ServiceData TestMethod()
 {
     ServiceData myServiceData = new ServiceData();

     myServiceData.Result = true;
     myServiceData.ErrorMessage = "Custom Error message.";
     myServiceData.ErrorDetails = "Error details of the exception";

     throw new FaultException<ServiceData>(myServiceData);
  }
```

I am getting exception at client end without using `FaultContact`. So why we need that?

Comment: A `FaultContract` represents a SOAP fault which is then sent to the client. You use `FaultContract` to encapsulate a server side error and send back some meaningful information within the context so the client can handle the situation gracefully..

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh - and so how does that make it any different from just throwing a SoapException?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh: My question is just we can send any server error by just using FaultException so why we need [FaultContract] attribute. if it's just working fine without that?

Comment: A fault contract is a message contract that details the set of exceptions that may be reported to the caller. You can specify the possible faults that can occur in your WCF service. This prevents exposing exception details beyond the defined set to your clients. Because a fault contract lists the types of errors that a WCF service can throw, it also allows your clients to distinguish between **contracted faults and other possible errors**.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same question today. I have only done research ... I have not tested anything. See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/fault-contract

Seems that you can configure the server to either send all fault exceptions to the client or only declared ones.

```
<behaviors>  
  <serviceBehaviors>  
    <behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">  
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>  
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />  
    </behavior>  
  </serviceBehaviors>  
</behaviors>
```

So, I think your server is configured to send all exceptions. For more security, you can change that to only send declared exceptions. And, then you will need to use the FaultContract attribute.

Microsoft says "This behavior [allowing all exceptions] should only be used for debugging purposes and should never be enabled in production."